# Find vector and angle on unit sphere given rotation matrix

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-geometry, isometry

Given that $-R_{u,\theta}=\frac13 \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2\\ 
2 & 1 & -2\\ 
2 & -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, find $u\in \mathbb{S}^2$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi]$.

I understand that one of the ways to solve for these is to get four equations from $PRP^T$, where $P$ is a change of basis (orthogonal) matrix. We can get one equation with $p_1, p_2, p_3$ from $PRP^T$, one equation from the fact that $u$ is a unit vector, then probably some equations from orthogonality. But there should be a much shorter and elegant way, although I have no idea about it.

Would appreciate your help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a $3$-dimensional rotation matrix $A$, the angle of rotation $\theta$
can be found by considering the trace of the matrix which is $1+2\cos\theta$. The axis of the rotation can be found by solving $(A-I)v=0$.

Comment: Should tr$(A)$ in $PAP^T=R$ be equal to the the sum of the eigenvalues of the matrix $R$?

Comment: @sequence The trace is the sum of eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, I mean that in this case $-1 = 1+2\cos\theta$? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @sequence Your matrix has trace $-1$, not $-1/3$.

Comment: Yes, just fixed that.

Comment: Can you please let me know how the condition $(A-I)v = 0$ is derived?

Comment: @sequence $A$ fixes the points on the axis of rotation.